# KubernetesPodOperator in Airflow 1.10.7

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

`KubernetesPodOperator` in Airflow 1.10.7 is imported `from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator` instead of `from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod` . I need to use the latter since the `airflow.contrib.*` is getting deprecated. Can I install the kubernetes module separately that uses the `airflow.providers.*`?